# Grails: Replacing symbols with HTML equivalent

Tags: grails, csv

I'm reading a CSV file and one of the columns has text that contains symbols that is not recognized. After I read the file, symbols such as ' becomes ∩┐╜ . I'm also saving this into a DB.

Obviously when I display this on a webpage, it shows garbage. How can I substitute HTML code (ex. &#180 ;) for this with Grails?

I am reading the CSV using the csv plugin. Code below:

```
def f = "clientDocs/testfile.csv"
def fReader = new File(f).toCsvMapReader([batchSize:50, charset:'UTF-8'])
fReader.each { batchList ->
batchList.each {
    def description = substituteSymbols(it.Description)


def substituteSymbols(inText) {
    // HOW TO SUBSTITUTE HERE
}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions. I've already tried string.replaceAll(regExp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails comes with a basic set of encoders/decoders for common tasks.

What you want here is `it.Description.encodeAsHTML()`.

And then if you want the original when displaying in the view, just reverse it with `.decodeHTML()`

You can read more about these here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#codecs

*(Edited decode method name typo as per the comment)*

Comment: The actual method name of the decode HTML codec in grails is decodeHTML instead of decodeAsHTML.